# C++: Can static variable be called in multiple files?

Tags: c++, c, static, arduino

I am looking at [ArduCopter](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/tree/master/ArduCopter) code. I see that there are few variables declared as static in [ArcuCopter.pde](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/ArduCopter.pde). However these variables are called in other .pde files. For example object g is defined [here](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/ArduCopter.pde#L199) as static and it is used in other [Attitude.pde](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/Attitude.pde) file many times like [this](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/Attitude.pde#L7) example.

As per my knowledge static memeber has a scope limited to a file and cannot be called in other file. So my question is how this can be done? Is there any way to access static member defined in other file as it is?

Comment: Please add minimum relevant code in your question and don't expect people to follow each link just to answer you.

Comment: @Gyapti There is no code from my end as I am trying to understand the concept from a particulate implementation hence I have to give enough external reference to put my query. So You have to go through links if you wish to understand my query.

Comment: @iharob When I try to call static variable from other file compiler gives me error saying cannot identify variable.

Comment: Yes I know extern works. But I would like to know how they are accessing varible in other file in ArduCopter code with static declaration

Comment: @iharob `You're confusing scope with lifetime. Static variables have a lifetime equal to the program's lifetime, but they still follow scoping rules based on where they are declared.` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152506/local-static-variable-scope-in-c)

Comment: @nikhil the variable declared with static and the other existed in other file are two distinct variables even if they have the same name  ! the static variable  hides the other global variable from its scope

Comment: @Meninx I also expected the fact you are suggesting. But the logic of code in ArduCopter suggests both variables used in different files are should be same

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps confusing 'file' and 'translation unit'.

Refer here http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.2

You can use identifiers for static objects declared in other **files** so long as they are part of the same **translation unit** (and appropriately declared at the point of use...).
A translation unit is a (normally notional) file made up of a source file (.c or .cpp probably) with all it's `#include` directives 'expanded'.

You can 'use' data declared static in another translation unit. But not an identifier. How?

**daft.h**:

```
static int x=0;

int nextX(void);
```

**daft.c**

```
#include "daft.h"

int nextX(void){
    return ++x;
}
```

**my.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "daft.h"

int main(void){

    printf("%d\n", nextX());//outputs 1.
    printf("%d\n", x);//prints 0.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where we assume that `daft.c` and `my.c` are source files. Both their translation units have an identifier `x` for an internally linked `int`.
The two identifiers and the storage for the objects are unrelated!
The call to `nextX()` accesses the storage for the identifier `x` internally linked in `daft.c`. The direct access `x` accesses the identifier internally linked in `my.c`.

Unless identifiers are declared `const` having `static` linkage identifiers in header files usually leads to trouble.